# DataGrip open Microsoft SQL Server Database File

Tags: sql-server, mdf, datagrip

Is there way how to open Microsoft SQL Server Database File (.mdf) in DataGrip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please understand that unlike CSV/TSV, the .mdf file is MS proprietary format and should/cannot be readable by any software not developed by MS.

To access data using datagrip either export data in non-proprietary format like TSV/CSV or import the .mdf file to local sql server instance.

You can then connect to local sql server instance from Datagrip using **[this tutorial](https://blog.jetbrains.com/datagrip/2016/10/07/connecting-datagrip-to-sql-server-express-localdb/)**

Comment: ach ok..  I didn't know that .mdf file is proprietary format. Thanks